# finding angle between a chord and a tangent

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

I am looking at a picture from a physics problem. On the right, we have $\delta \theta / 2$ for the angle between the tangent at the center of the small arc and the chord between the middle and lower(upper) point. I am not aware of a geometric result that guarantees this. Is this a mere approximation or an actual result?

Comment: It’s not an approximation. The $T$ arrow is perpendicular to the lower radius, so a bit of angle-chasing will establish the result.

Comment: @DavidQuinn How do you see that the T arrow is perpendicular to the lower radius? I'm not sure what you mean by angle-chasing.

Comment: The rope is tangent to the circle at the endpoints of the arc. The tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius of the circle. Angle chasing just means drawing a picture and indicating which angle is what (using complemetary angles and such).

Comment: @DavidQuinn Could you provide a more detailed answer to the angle chasing part here?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the diagram, $x$ indicates the angle $\frac{\delta\theta}{2}$ in your original diagram.

The obtuse angle opposite the $x$ between the two tangents is $180^o-x$ due to the fact that a quadrilateral has total internal angle $360^o$ and the other two angles between the tangents and the radii are $90^o$.

Then, since a straight line is $180^o$, the external angle indicated is also $x$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much your diagram makes it much easier to see the result as the quadrilateral is clear.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: One more question is $T \sin x$ parallel to the middle line past the radius? I think it is because the opposite side will be perpendicular to the middle tangent line.

Comment: Yes. $T\cos x$ acts along the tangent at the centre of the arc, and $T\sin x$ is perpendicular to that, acting along the central radius